# como cambiar el color de celda de una tabla html

Tags: javascript, html

mi pregunta es la seguiente tengo una tabla en html la cual se llena con unos valores aleatorios mediante js, como puedo que al dar click sobre una celda pueda pintarla de un color.

```js
$("#celda-a-pintar").click(function(){ 
   document.getElementById('celda-a-pintar').style.backgroundColor = "blue"

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<table id="table" border="1">


<tr>

<td id="celda-a-pintar">&nbsp;</td>
<td id="celda-a-pintar2">&nbsp;</td>

</tr>

</table>
</html>
```

Comment: Detecta la fila y columna de la celda y usa document.getElementById('table').rows[renglon].cells[columna].style.backgroundColor = "blue";

Answer (score 4):

Tu problema está en el selector, estás haciendo referencia al primer `td` por el `id`.
Con el siguiente selector harás referencia a todos los `td` de la tabla

```
$("#table tr td")
```

y para pintarlo ya que estas usando jQuery, puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
$("#table tr td").click(function(){
    $(this).css("background-color", "blue");
});
```

```js
$("#table tr td").click(function(){
  $(this).css("background-color", "blue");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<table id="table" border="1">


<tr>

<td id="celda-a-pintar">&nbsp;</td>
<td id="celda-a-pintar2">&nbsp;</td>

</tr>

</table>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

De acuerdo a tu código debes definir la tabla y definir la fila(s) (`rows[]`) y columna(s) (`cells[]`) de la celda que deseas cambiar de color.

Ejemplo, en este caso pintara la celda ubicada en el primer renglón `rows[0]`, segunda columna `cells[1]`:

```
 //document.getElementById('celda-a-pintar').style.backgroundColor = "blue"
 document.getElementById('table').rows[0].cells[1].style.backgroundColor = "blue";
```

De acuerdo a lo anterior ahora un ejemplo en el cual detecta la celda y la hace cambiar de color:

```js
  $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#table').on( 'click', 'td', function () {
            row = $(this).closest("tr").index();          
            col = $(this).closest("td").index();    
            document.getElementById('table').rows[row].cells[col].style.backgroundColor = "blue";
          console.log("pinta renglon: " + row + " columna: " + col);
        });
  });
```

```html
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <html>
    <table id="table" border="1">


    <tr>

    <td id="celda-a-pintar">&nbsp;</td>
    <td id="celda-a-pintar2">&nbsp;</td>
    <td id="celda-a-pintar3">&nbsp;</td>
    <td id="celda-a-pintar4">&nbsp;</td>
    <td id="celda-a-pintar5">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>

    </table>
    </html>
```